# How to find the smallest bounding sphere when given a set of points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm trying to figure this out using some variant of quadratic programming. I'm taking a class that covered optimization techniques, and I get the impression that this problem is solvable using Lagrangian optimization / KKT conditions, but I'm not sure where to start. I've tried to read papers on Fischer's exact solver, but that seems out of the scope of the class.

Comment: I would suggest making the question more explicit.  I'm guessing, but given a set of $n$ points $x_1, \dots, x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (maybe $d = 2$ or $d = 3$), you want to find the smallest sphere such that all points lie within or on the sphere.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The problem that I am trying to solve would be for all d, but given an algorithm for d=2 or d=3, it should be a good starting point for me to generalize.

Comment: The following may be a possibility: Compute $|x_i - x_j|$ for all $i \neq j$.  Let $r = \frac{1}{2} \max |x_i - x_j|$ and $z = \frac{x_i + x_j}{2}$, where $x_i, x_j$ are the points achieving the maximum.  Then, the sphere you want is the sphere of radius $r$ centered at $z$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Find the convex hull. There are efficient algorithms for that.

Comment: What about points located at the corners of an equilateral triangle?  Your procedure does not hold there.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.